# Filter all rows that do not contain letters (alpha) in ´pandas´

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a `pandas` dataframe using `regular expressions`.
I want to delete those rows that do not contain any letters. For example:

```
Col A.
50000
$927848
dog
cat 583
rabbit 444
```

My desired results is:

```
Col A.
dog
cat 583
rabbit 444
```

I have been trying to solve this problem unsuccessful with `regex` and `pandas` filter options. See blow. I am specifically running into problems when I try to merge two conditions for the filter. How can I achieve this?

Option 1:

```
df['Col A.'] = ~df['Col A.'].filter(regex='\d+')
```

Option 2

```
df['Col A.'] = df['Col A.'].filter(regex=\w+)
```

Option 3

```
from string import digits, letters
df['Col A.'] = (df['Col A.'].filter(regex='|'.join(letters)))
```

OR

```
df['Col A.'] = ~(df['Col A.'].filter(regex='|'.join(digits)))
```

OR

```
df['Col A.'] = df[~(df['Col A.'].filter(regex='|'.join(digits))) & (df['Col A.'].filter(regex='|'.join(letters)))]
```

Comment: Is regular expression a requirement?

Comment: @jpp no regular expression is not a requirement. Just the approach that I have followed thus far

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you'd need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to filter values which contain letters by the means of [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df =  df[df['Col A.'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]
print (df)
       Col A.
2         dog
3     cat 583
4  rabbit 444
```

If there are some `NaN`s values you can pass a parameter:

```
df = df[df['Col A.'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]', na=False)]    
print (df)
       Col A.
3         dog
4     cat 583
5  rabbit 444
```

Comment: For me, this soution is removing all that is not a letter. It strips the instances of mixed characters that I have

Comment: If cast to `str` it help? `df[df['Col A.'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-Za-z]')]` ?

Comment: And is not need filter values which contains at least one letter? It is not same as removing  all that is not a letter?

Comment: it is a cleaning and I need to filter out those instances where there is not AT LEAST 1 alpha letter in the row.

Comment: Hmmm, so my solution failed? I think it should works nice.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
df['Col A.'].filter(regex=r'\D')  # Keeps only if there's a non-digit character
```

or:

```
df['Col A.'].filter(regex=r'[A-Za-z]')  # Keeps only if there's a letter (alpha)
```

or:

```
df['Col A.'].filter(regex=r'[^\W\d_]')  # More info in the link below...
```

Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2039476/8933502

Answer (score 2):

`df['Col A.'].str.contains(r'^\d+$', na=True)` # if string with only digits or if int/float then will result in NaN converted to True

eg: [50000, '$927848', 'dog', 'cat 583', 'rabbit 444', '3 e 3', 'e 3', '33', '3 e'] 
will give : 
[True,False,False,False,False,False,False, True,False]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^.*[a-zA-Z].*$`

https://regex101.com/r/b84ji1/1

**Details**

`^`: Start of the line

`.*`: Match any character

`[a-zA-Z]`: Match letters

`$`: End of the line

Comment: Since some of the rows have a combination of letters and digits, this approach actually filters all of my data. I am just interested in removing those rows that do not contain AT LEAST 1 letter

Comment: This is working with your test case. It keep only string with at least one letter. I don't understand what is wrong for you ?