# Using Japanese delimiters in re package

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text and want to extract `'- あらたなるきぼう'` which is between `'('` and the Japanese character  `'、'`

```
st1='『スター・ウォーズ エピソード4/新たなる希望』（ - あらたなるきぼう、Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope)'
```

I used two regex methods to extract what I wanted but neither of them worked.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  import  re
  st1='『スター・ウォーズ エピソード4/新たなる希望』（ - あらたなるきぼう、Sta    r Wars Episode IV: A New Hope)'
  m1 = re.search('\(([^、]*).*、.*\)',st1)
  m2 = re.search('\((.*?)、.+?\)',st1).group(1)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Of course I could use the split method, first on `'、'`  then on `'('` . First of all it is ugly and not robust and second for some reason it does not split by `'('`:

```
st1.split('、')[0].split('(')`
```

Comment: Try using codepoints in the regex (if Python supports that).

Comment: It is often worth testing regular expressions with e.g. http://regex101.com/#python, which can show you exactly what you're capturing (or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first character is:

```
（
```

not:

```
(
```

These are distinct characters. The first is the [FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff08/index.htm). The second is the normal ascii open parenthesis.

You must use a unicode string with the right unicode character to get a match:

```
>>> st1=u'『スター・ウォーズ エピソード4/新たなる希望』（ - あらたなるきぼう、Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope)'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(u'（([^、]*).*、.*\)',st1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103717738>
```

Comment: I know I can simplify, but I intentionally left it as close to OP's regex as possible.

Comment: Nice observation on the （, could have figured it out myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 2.x, try making the regex string a unicode-escape string, with 'u'. Since it's regex it's good practice to make your regex string a raw string, with 'r'. Also, putting your entire pattern in parentheses is superfluous.

Refer [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) or [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode)