# Python match key with accented characters in a regex with Python

Tags: python, regex

This is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import re

with open("/Users/paul/Desktop/file.json") as json_file:
    file = json.load(json_file)
print file["desc"]

key="capacità"
result = re.findall("((?:[\S,]+\s+){0,3})"+key+"\s+((?:[\S,]+\s*){0,3})", file["desc"], re.IGNORECASE)
print result
```

This is the content of the file

```
{
    "desc": "Frigocongelatore, capacit\u00e0 di 215 litri, h 122 cm, classe A+"
}
```

My result is []

but what I want is result = "capacità"

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5096928/797495

Comment: I originally voted the other one as a duplicate of this one, but arguably it should be the other way around.  The original question is messier, but has answers and discussion.