# Find and replace both quotation styles in Python unicoded string

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I'm trying to replace strings marked in both quotation mark styles (“...” and "...") on a string in Python.

I've already written a regex to replace the standard quotations

```
print re.sub(r'\"(.+?)\"', r'<em>"\1"</em>', self.title)
```

When I try to do it for the literary (?) ones it doesn't replace anything.

```
return re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', self.title)
```

In fact, as I have it right now, I can't even make a conditional query:

```
quote_list = ['“', '”']

if all(character in self.title for character in quote_list):
    print "It has literary quotes"
    print re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', self.title)
print re.sub(r'\"(.+?)\"', r'<em>"\1"</em>', self.title)
```

**EDIT**: Further context: It's an object

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def render_title(self):
    """
    This function wraps italics around quotation marks
    """
    quote_list = ['“', '”']

    if all(character in self.title for character in quote_list):
        print "It has literary quotes"
        return re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', self.title)
    return re.sub(r'\"(.+?)\"', r'<em>"\1"</em>', self.title)
```

I am not well-versed in regex commands. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT2**: One step closer to the problem! It lies with the fact that I'm dealing with unicoded strings. I'm still stumped as how I can solve this. Any help is appreciated!

```
>>> title = u"sdsfgsdfgsdgfsdgs “ asd” asd"
>>> print re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', title)
sdsfgsdfgsdgfsdgs “ asd” asd
>>> title = "sdsfgsdfgsdgfsdgs “ asd” asd"
>>> print re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', title)
sdsfgsdfgsdgfsdgs <em>“ asd”</em> asd
```

Comment: Well, your code works for me, what's the problem?

Comment: Does `print self.title` show you the quotes correctly? Please show an example of the exact string you're running this on.

Comment: Perhaps the left and right quotation marks are encoded as entities such as `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`

Comment: @Kevin I've edited with further context

Comment: @interjay: See edit. I think I found the problem. It works if I use a normal string but not unicode e.g.: u"It has “literary” quotes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. After printing the variable as suggested by @interjay I found out that the string was unicoded.

Comparing it with a simple string didn't work so I removed the conditional and used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode) to simply make an unicode-escaped regex string to handle both simple and "literary" quotes.

```
title = re.sub(ur'\“(.+?)\”', ur'“<em>\1</em>”', self.title)  # notice the ur
title = re.sub(ur'\"(.+?)\"', ur'"<em>\1</em>"', title)
```

I've seen here in a comment (unfortunately now deleted) how one could merge the above two sentences in one, but for now it works.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
quote_list = ['“', '”']
title = "“...”"

if all(character in title for character in quote_list):
    print "It has literary quotes"
    print re.sub(r'\“(.+?)\”', r'<em>“\1”</em>', title)
```

1. Please check if you encoding supports the characters that you are using. I am here using utf-8 which supports quotes that you have used, and everything worked well.
2. your if condition might not be true at all, check if the condition can every be true. `all` return true when every element is `Truthy`

Ensure where ever when you compare or use regexpression the coding format is same. support using a unicode regexp pattern against a unicode string

```
quote_list = [u'“', u'”']
title = u"“...”"

if all(character in title for character in quote_list):
   print "It has literary quotes"
   print re.sub(u'\“(.+?)\”', u'<em>“\1”</em>', title)
```

Comment: The characters are supported. What I found was that it replaces strings well, but not unicoded strings. Using your example: u"“...”"

Comment: Please see EDIT 2. Thanks