# Python - using regex to extract certain words from HTML file (converted from docx)

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, ms-word

I have a problem that I require help with. I wish to extract text with certain features from html and put them into a list, specifically: ALL words that are bold and that have quotes around them eg.

"**Word**"

In HTML that will be :

`This is actually a very complicated sentence ("<strong>CS</strong>"), I hope you understand it.`

I wish to extract the word 'CS' and put it into a list ['CS'].

This is what I have at the moment, note that I'm converting a word document into HTML format and extracting texts from the HTML file:

```
with open(r'file path.docx', 'rb') as file:
    html = mammoth.convert_to_html(file).value
    result =re.findall('&quot;<strong>(.*?)</strong>&quot;',html)
```

But I seem to have a bit of trouble as this doesn't yield all the results that I want.

Thanks guys for your help! I know that there is a package called BeautifulSoup if you could tell me how that works in this case, it would be great as well!

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string where it doesn't find the desired pattern (since @CC7052 answer looks good)?

Comment: for instance, in this sentence, none of the words are identified:
I have been instructed by Business Advisory Services LLP (“<strong>BAS</strong>”), before the High Court of Justice – (the “<strong>Court</strong>”)."

Comment: The duplicate question does not answer question.  The user is already using a regex to find a pattern.  The real problem is the quote style in the user's pattern string is different from the quote style in the string.   The string is using quotes from `quote_list = ['“', '”']`, which corresponds to Unicode 8220 and 8221 while the pattern is using the quote style `"` which corresponds to Unicode 34.  This can be fixed by replacing quotes in the string that uses quotes from quote_list with `"`.

Comment: [Example of previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782513/find-and-replace-both-quotation-styles-in-python-unicoded-string)