# Python regex with devanAgarI

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
# Prerequisite: sudo easy_install regex
import regex
import sys
import collections

test = True

lines = []
if (test):
  test_lines = """
अ पु. संस्कृत वर्णमाला का प्रथम वर्ण [विशेषतया तीन दिन
तक चलने वाले सोम-याग (त्रिरात्र) के प्रथम दिन आज्य
इति”, पञ्च. ब्रा. 2०.14.3।
अंश पु.1 अ. भाग (देवों, पितरों एवं मनुष्यों के लिए नियत)
ऋ.वे. 1०.31.3; अ.वे. 11.1.5;1 ब. पशु-भाग, बौ.श्रौ.सू.
का नाम, ऋ. प्रा. 17.4; निदा.सू. 1०5.2०।
""".split("\n")
  lines = test_lines
else:
  lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

full_text = "\n".join(lines)
full_text = regex.sub(ur'^(\S+)\s+(पु[ .])', '####\g<1>####\g<1> \g<2>', full_text, flags=regex.UNICODE|regex.MULTILINE)
print(full_text)
```

I expect the above to produce the following output:

```
    ####अ####अ पु. संस्कृत वर्णमाला का प्रथम वर्ण [विशेषतया तीन दिन
    तक चलने वाले सोम-याग (त्रिरात्र) के प्रथम दिन आज्य
    इति”, पञ्च. ब्रा. 2०.14.3।
    ####अंश####अंश पु.1 अ. भाग (देवों, पितरों एवं मनुष्यों के लिए नियत)
    ऋ.वे. 1०.31.3; अ.वे. 11.1.5;1 ब. पशु-भाग, बौ.श्रौ.सू.
    का नाम, ऋ. प्रा. 17.4; निदा.सू. 1०5.2०।
```

But I get unaltered text.

Comment: Your input should also be Unicode, not only the pattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WiktorStribiżew pointed out, when dealing with Unicode text, the strings should be Unicode.

You must be using Python 2, so change:

```
test_lines = """
```

to:

```
test_lines = u"""
```

Also, for `stdin` change:

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

to:

```
lines = [line.decode(sys.stdin.encoding) for line in sys.stdin]
```