# Python regex: pattern with re.ASCII can still match unicode characters?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ascii

I am new to Python regex and am trying to match non-white space ASCII characters in Python.

The following is my code:

```
impore re

p = re.compile(r"[\S]{2,3}", re.ASCII)

p.search('1234')  # have some result

p.search('你好吗') # also have result, but Why?
```

I have specified ASCII mode in `re.compile`, but `p.search('你好吗')` still have result. I wonder what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you have to use `\u` refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393843/python-and-regular-expression-with-unicode

Comment: re.ASCII is not what you think, in this case

Comment: @NikosM. so what does it mean? The doc says it will enforce ASCII mode if I understand correctly.

Comment: @jdhao still non-space is non-space even in enforced ascii mode, this is what you get, does not matter if is unicode, it is non-space even in enforced ascii

Comment: @NikosM.N I kind of get the point. In ASCII mode, it is equivalent to `[^ \t\n\r\f\v]`. So unicode  characters should match. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `re.A` flag only affects what *shorthand character classes* match.

**In Python 3.x, [shorthand character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) are Unicode aware, the [Python 2.x `re.UNICODE`/`re.U`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) is ON by default.** That means:

- `\d`: *Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category **[Nd]**)*
- `\D`: *Matches any character which is not a decimal digit.* (So, all characters other than those in the [`Nd` Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)).
- `\w`  - *Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore.* (So, `\w+` matches each word in a `My name is Виктор` string)
- `\W` - *Matches any character which is not a word character. This is the opposite of `\w`.* (So, it will not match any Unicode letter or digit.)
- `\s` - *Matches Unicode whitespace characters* (it will match `NEL`, hard spaces, etc.)
- `\S` - *Matches any character which is not a whitespace character.* (So, no match for `NEL`, hard space, etc.)
- `\b` - word boundaries match locations between Unicode letters/digits and non-letters/digits or start/end of string.
- `\B` - non-word boundaries match locations between two Unicode letters/digits, two non-letters/digits or between a Unicode non-letter/digit and start/end of string.

**If you want to disable this behavior**, you use `re.A` or `re.ASCII`:

> Make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S` perform ASCII-only matching instead of full Unicode matching. This is only meaningful for Unicode patterns, and is ignored for byte patterns. Corresponds to the inline flag `(?a)`.

That means that:

- `\d` = `[0-9]` - and no longer matches Hindi, Bengali, etc. digits
- `\D` = `[^0-9]` - and matches any characters other than ASCII digits (i.e. it acts as `(?u)(?![0-9])\d` now)
- `\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]` - and it only matches ASCII words now, `Wiktor` is matched with `\w+`, but `Виктор` does not
- `\W` = `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` - it matches any char but ASCII letters/digits/`_` (i.e. it matches `你好吗`, `Виктор`, etc.
- **`\s` = `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` - matches a regular space, tab, linefeed, carriage return, form feed and a vertical tab**
- **`\S` = `[^ \t\n\r\f\v]` - matches any char other than a space, tab, linefeed, carriage return, form feed and a vertical tab, so it matches all Unicode letters, digits and punctuation and Unicode (non-ASCII) whitespace.** E.g., `re.sub(r'\S+', r'{\g<0>}', '\xA0  ', flags=re.A)` will return `'{ }  '`, as you see, the `\S` now matches hard spaces.