# Regex for italian tags

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm working on a regex to take @users
In italian, sometime there is something like l'@Orazio.
I can't find the right way to take this.

I'm using this line `/(?<=^|\s)(@(\S+))/`

this is my online tester
https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/12

as you can see I have an issue with the case 4

Any tips?

Comment: You [have made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092338/regex-for-italian-tags/63092368?noredirect=1#comment111569670_63092390) the question too unclear. Please update the question body with: 1) full list of requirements, 2) **relevant**-only code you are using to repro the issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an optional group:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?:\w?'?)(@(\S+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/5

For more than 1 letter in front, use:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?:(\w*')?)(@(\S+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/8

And to match all your updated cases:

https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/10

For different types of apostrophes:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?:(\w*['´])?)(@(\S+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/13

Comment: it doesn't work if I use "dell'@altro"

Comment: @J.Luca updated the answer, use `(?<=^|\s)(?:(\w*')?)(@(\S+))`

Comment: watched. It looks good! Thanks!

Comment: Updated it once more to have all your test cases

Comment: just noted that it does not work because the ['] is added using the html code &#39;. Any tips?

Comment: See update for different types of apostrophes

Comment: it's not an apostrophe. It is &#39;

Comment: The single quotation mark is the same as unicode: `U+2019`. try with something similar as what suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/393856/7445528

Comment: You might also use the re.UNICODE flag

Comment: Can I not solve with a regex?

Comment: You can definitely solve it with a regex. Try adding the re.UNICODE flag and exchanging the `'` with the unicode value: `U+2019`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)(?:\w+['’])?@(\S+)
(?<!\w)(?:\w+['’])?@(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQMlx5/3)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - whitespace or start of string must appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!\w)` - a location the is not immediately preceded with a word char
- `(?:\w+['’])?` - an optinal sequence of 1+ word chars and then `'` or `’`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: [l'] is just an example. It happens also with [dell'], [all'], etc.

Comment: @J.Luca Ok, fixed. If you need specific substrings only, use `(?:dell|all|l)` instead of `\w+`

Comment: just watched your edit :) how to "create" two groups?

Comment: @J.Luca You may simply use your `(@(\S+))`. You do not not need to wrap the whole match with additional group. What is the code you are using it in?

Comment: check out the first post. Just edited. https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/7

Comment: @J.Luca See https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/9. In the replacement, `$0` is the whole match, `$1` is Group 1. Of course, you may use [your two group approach](https://regex101.com/r/s5BTm0/11), but that is extra overhead for the regex engine. My regex demo - https://regex101.com/r/5Uehqs/1.

Comment: @J.Luca I wonder if you need even more strict rules. `\w` matches `_` and digits. If you only need to allow *letters*, I'd recommend `(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{L}+['’])?@(\S+)` where `\p{L}` matches a letter. Or even ``(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{L}+['’])?@(\S+)\b``, so that the end punctuation gets truncated.